# Как получить URL изображения из определенного канала?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Если в определенном канале с ID 111111111111111111, пользователь отправляет изображение, нужно получить URL этого изображения, и записать его в переменную.

Алгоритм действий примерно такой:

```
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    def url_parser():
        if message.content == Фотография:
            photo_url = URL фотографии
```

Как это сделать, чтобы работало?

Comment: если пользователь отправляет сообщение, которое содержит изображение*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изображение в [аттаче](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments) содержит же url, его и присвойте:

```
photo_url = message.attachments[0].url
```

Comment: А если в этом сообщении нет фото? Как в if операторе задать условие, если есть фото в сообщении?

Comment: @BlitGaming if message.attachments: photo_url = message.attachments[0].url

Comment: @Jack_oS, любая ссылка в attachments - это фото? Как-то подозрительно, там что, нельзя ни файлы пересылать, ни видео?

Comment: Возможно ли взять не полное изображение, а url его миниатюры? 
На канале изображения сжатые отображаются, этот способ берёт оригинальный размер. Можно ли взять тот самый сжатый с канала?